# UICollectionviewcells disappear after initiating interactive movement and re-order with custom layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollectionview` with a custom layout as a sub-view of a `UIViewcontroller`. I want to drag my cells and have the collection view reorder the cells when the cell being dragged moves into the bounds of a cell not being dragged. This functionality is given when you're using a collection view. However, once I add my own layout, cells begin to disappear after initiating interactive movement.

**This is how I set up my customFlow layout:**

```
private var frames = [CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0),//0
                      CGRect(x: 40.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0),//1
                      CGRect(x: 80.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0),//2
                      CGRect(x: 100.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0),//3
                      CGRect(x: 120.0, y: 0.0, width: 40.0, height: 40.0)]//4

private var cache = [NSIndexPath:UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

override func prepareLayout() {
    super.prepareLayout()
    for item in 0 ..< collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(0){
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
        let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: indexPath)

        attributes.frame = frames[item]
        cache[indexPath] = attributes
    }


}


override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
    return UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size
}

override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
    for attributes in cache.values {
        if CGRectIntersectsRect(attributes.frame, rect) {
            layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
        }
    }
    return layoutAttributes

}

override func layoutAttributesForInteractivelyMovingItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath, withTargetPosition position: CGPoint) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {
    let attribute = cache[indexPath]
    attribute!.center = position
    return attribute!
   }

}
```

**This is how I initiate interactive movement:**

```
func handleLongPressForCollection(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer){
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.CollectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        CollectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(CollectionView))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
        break
    }
}
```

I don't understand `invalidatelayout` very well. I think I need it to solve this issue? I've tried overriding the function  `invalidationContextForEndingInteractiveMovementOfItemsToFinalIndexPaths`
but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue and found out the cause was that I was not calling the parent in the overridden functions. From your code, I see you are not retrieving the current layout attributes from the parent in the `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect` function. You must do that in the first line of that method: `var layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)`